# Is a QTimer in a background thread updated even if the main thread is busy?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, qthread, qtimer

Let's say I have a PyQt GUI application and a `QTimer` running in the background using a `QThread`. The `QTimer` is set to an interval of 1 second and is running infinitely.

Now the main thread gets busy with some external C library call and blocks for 1 minute. Will the `QTimer` continue to get triggered during that period and signal it?

I am in a conceptual stage so there is no code to show yet. I know it would make more sense to do the big call in a background thread itself.

Comment: The signals will all get backed up in the event-queue of the receiving thread. When control returns to the main thread, the signals will all be processed at the same time. So if you care about *exactly when* something occurs (in real time), you may need to take that into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short words, **yes, QTimer will update on the other thread**, granted that you take care of the thread's lifespan yourself and quit it only at the most appropriate times. Also be careful about the `QTimer's` reference, so it is not collected by the python's garbage collector (you'll need to stop the `QTimer` at one point).

Now, with a bit of code to illustrate a more practical example, and so you can test it yourself:

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QPushButton
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject, QThread, QTimer, Signal

class TimerWorker(QObject):
    timeout = Signal(int)

    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        self.count = 0

    def run(self):
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(250)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.process)
        self.timer.start()

    def finished(self):
        self.timer.stop()

    def process(self):
        self.count += 1
        self.timeout.emit(self.count)

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        # Widgets
        self.scene = QWidget()
        self.label = QLabel("Count: 0")
        self.busyBt = QPushButton("Sleep")
        self.busyBt.clicked.connect(self.becomeBusy)

        # Scene
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.busyBt)
        self.scene.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.scene)

        # Threads
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.worker = TimerWorker()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.worker.timeout.connect(self.processCount)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.worker.finished)
        self.thread.start()

    def becomeBusy(self):
        timeout = 5
        print('Main Thread: Sleeping for %d seconds...' % (timeout))
        QThread.sleep(timeout)
        print('Main Thread: Awaken')

    def processCount(self, count):
        self.label.setText("Count: %d" % (count))

    def closeEvent(self, evt):
        self.thread.quit()
        self.thread.wait()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication()
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    app.exec_()
```

In this example, we start a `QThread` which executes `TimerWorker.run()` on the *other thread* (using the moveToThread method). At each 0.25 seconds, it emits a signal that is scheduled on the *main thread*, to update the `QLabel` text.

At the same time, the user can click a `QPushButton` to stop the main thread for 5 seconds. During that time, the application will freeze.

---

By executing the script and clicking on the `QPushButton` to freeze the main thread, the `QTimer` keeps running and emitting the signal from the *other thread*. But as the *main thread* is sleeping (or busy), the signal is never processed. The signal will only be processed after the *main thread* awakes.

So, if you need to keep the GUI always responsive for the Client (and always processing emitted signals), its recomended that you do all the *heavy work* on the `QThread` side, to not keep the application frozen for a time.

Comment: Thank you so much for this elaborate in-depth answer

Comment: One additional note: If code is called in the main thread that locks the GIL, e.g. in a C extension that didn't care about it, this will effectively halt everything while it runs. The TimerWorker will not run in real time then. One can remedy this by releasing the GIL in the extension code: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#releasing-the-gil